# Cube.java:19: error: constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

I cannot figure out why my code will not compile. I keep getting different codes. Here is the latest: Cube.java:19: error: constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types;

Can anyone assist me in figuring this out?

```
public class Cube 
{
   private double height;
   private double width;
   private double depth;
   private double surfaceArea;
   private double volume;

   public Cube(double h, double w, double d)
   {
      super(h,w);
      depth = d;
   }

   public void setDepth(double d)
   {
      depth = d;
   }

   public double getDepth()    
   {
      return depth;    
   }

   public double computeSurfaceArea()    
   {    
      height = super.getHeight();    
      width = super.getWidth();    
      surfaceArea = (2 * height * width) + (2 * width * depth) + (2 * height * depth);    
      return surfaceArea;    
   }

   public double computeVolume()
   {
      volume= (height*width*depth);    
      return volume;    
   }

}
```

Error message:

Cube.java:19: error: constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
super(h,w);
^
  required: no arguments
  found: double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to format your code - see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for details. I assume you've *actually* got the code in a form without all the extra blank lines and lack of indentation. If you put it as-is, but within triple-backticks, your code will be significantly easier to read.

Comment: But your problem is caused by this line: `super(h,w);` What do you expect that to do, given that the superclass of `Cube` is just `java.lang.Object`? Perhaps you meant to specify that `Cube` extends some other class?

Comment: I found [Inheritance in Java with Example Programs](http://www.beginwithjava.com/java/inheritance/what-is-inheritance.html) which seems to be what you are trying to do. Your `Cube` class is the same as the `Box` class in that example. I suggest you go back to your example and check whether the `Cube` class extends another class,

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure u declare an base class  (which in your case I assume is box)

```
class Box
{
  protected double height,width;

  protected Box(double h,double w)
  { 
    height=h;
    width=w;
   }
 }
```

Next make sure your cube class extends from it

```
class Cube extends Box
{
   private double depth;
   private double surfaceArea;
   private double volume;

 public Cube(double h, double w, double d)
   {
      super(h,w);
      depth = d;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Cube(double h, double w, double d)

{
height = h;

width = w;

depth = d;

}

public double computeSurfaceArea() {

surfaceArea = (2 * height * width) + (2 * width * depth) + (2 * height * depth);

return surfaceArea;

}
```

Comment: I am getting the error here: super(h,w);     I will try this